# Passing a class or something similar as a parameter with default

Tags: c#

I am trying to find a quick fix for an issue we have. I need to pass multiple optional parameters to multiple static methods and i also need to pass a couple new `params Type[]` parameters to add.

Obviously you can't have i.e. `params string[] param1` with other optional parameters.

Currently the best option i thought about was to create a custom class with a simple `params` in the constructor.

The problem is that i can't find a way to setup a default value to make the parameter optional as it ask for a constant value and i can't have that with a class. I also cannot make the parameter non optional as it shows error on every 70,000+ references.

So i would like to find a way to do the following somehow

```
public class CustomClass
{ 
    public CustomClass(params string[] stringParams)
    {
            
    }
}


public static object GenerateData(Manager manager, 
                                  string param1, 
                                  int param2, 
                                  string optionalParam1 = "incomplete", 
                                  CustomClass paramsClass = new CustomClass("val1","val2"))
{
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public static object GenerateData(Manager manager,
                                  string param1,
                                  int param2,
                                  string optionalParam1 = "incomplete",
                                  CustomClass paramsClass = null)
{
    paramsClass = paramsClass ?? new CustomClass("val1", "val2");
    return "";
}
```

Keep in mind, if this method resides in a library and those 70,000 calls are in something that references your library (rather than being in the same assembly, which you will recompile after this change), this is a *breaking change*.  Just because you add an optional parameter doesn't mean existing code will work if you don't recompile that code.

Comment: I totally forgot i could force null and set in the method. This works perfectly. No need to edit all references for months.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe *extract class* for `GeneratingData` parameters?

```
public sealed class Generator {
  public Manager Manager         {get;}
  public string Param1           {get;}
  public int Param2              {get;}
  public string OptionalParam1   {get; init;} = "incomplete";
  public CustomClass ParamsClass {get; init;} = new CustomClass("val1", "val2");

  // Mandatory values only
  public Generator(Manager manager,
                   string param1, 
                   int param2) {
    Manager = manager;
    Param1  = param1;
    Param2  = param2;
  }

  public object GenerateData() {
    //TODO: Actual generation here
    return "";
  }
}
```

So, instead of calling `static` methods you can call the constructor and initializer:

```
// Create generator and generate value
var result = new Generator(myManager, myParam1, myParam2) {  
  // Change optional parameter
  OptionalParam1 = "complete",
}.GenerateData();
```

Whenever you want to add new optional property all you have to do is to add a property into `Generator`:

```
  ...
  public string MyOtherOptionalProperty {get; init;} = "My Default Value";
  ...
```